# UPDATE SET syntax PHP

Tags: php, set

```
<?php
include_once"scripts/connect.php";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tabletest ORDER BY Points DESC, PP DESC, Name ASC");

$pos=1;
  while($pos <= 16){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  $Points = $row['Points'];
  $PP = $row['PP'];
  $Name = $row['Name'];

  mysql_query("UPDATE Tabletest SET thiswp=".$pos." WHERE Points=".$Points." PP=".$PP."        Name=".$Name."");
  echo "$pos $Points $Name $PP <br/> \n";
  $pos = $pos + 1;
  }
?>
```

This echoes out as I would expect i.e.

```
Position Points  Name PP
1        5       John 55
2        4       Bob  54
3        4       Jane 54
4        3       Rob  50
etc
```

But it doesn't update Tabletest - the thiswp field is left blank. Where have I messed up?
Cheers
Rich

Comment: Sorry the goes over my head - do you mean it's vulnerable to sql injection? or it's erroring with a "sql injection detected"

Comment: it's vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: You should look at your PHP error logs -- especially if you are not going to error-check your SQL calls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out `AND`.

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE Tabletest SET thiswp=".$pos." WHERE Points=".$Points." AND PP=".$PP." AND Name='".mysql_real_escape_string($Name)."'");
```

Edit: Also, just in case Name was a string, it should have had 'single quotes' around it and have been escaped, as above. Same goes for anything else that was a string.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause. it's wrong.

Usually it consists of logical operators.